# Saving xlsx file into another folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I specify the path to folder2 in order to save my excel file?  I don't want to use an absolute path, I want to able to save the file into folder regardless where the `app` folder is located.

I have the following folder data structure:

```
-app
    -folder1
        - file1.py
    -folder2
         -myexcelfile.xlsx
    main.py
```

Inside my file1.py I have some script that creates a pandas dataframe and I want to save it as an XLSX to folder2

```
df = to_excel("folder2path")
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be a parent path:

```
df = to_excel("../folder2/myexcelfile.xlsx")
```

Comment: I get an error saying that ``no such file or directory``

Comment: `df = to_excel("./folder2/myexcelfile.xlsx")` seems to work

Comment: Yes sorry, your 'working directory' (where the file1.py is run from) is the 'app' directory. I'd assumed it was app/folder1